# Wrapping method with default argument that is a null pointer to another wrapped type

Tags: c++, boost-python

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
struct A { };

struct B {
    void f(A *a = nullptr) const;
};
```

How can I wrap this properly using `boost::python`? In particular the default argument.

The following generates a `SystemError` (*initialization of xxx raised unreported exception*) when importing the module:

```cpp
bpy::class_<B>
    // Explicitly converting the nullptr to A* does not solve this:
    .def("f", &B::f, bpy::arg("a") = nullptr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was quite... simple, in the end. Just need to wrap the null pointer in a `bpy::ptr`:

```cpp
bpy::class_<B>
    // The cast to A* is mandatory otherwise bpy::ptr cannot deduce the type:
    .def("f", &B::f, bpy::arg("a") = bpy::ptr((A*)nullptr));
```